# What tools are out there to audit changes to Java interfaces?

Tags: java

Does anyone know of any tools out there which can summarize changes to Java interfaces between different versions?  (By interface I mean the exposed functionality of types in general, not the specific language construct.)

What I would like is some program which takes two versions of the same package or package tree and outputs something like:

- Constructor (String, int) removed on class Thing

  Constructor (String) deprecated on class OtherThing

  Method void setId(String) added on class SomethingElse

or something more sophisticated, the above is just my initial thoughts.  A solution could work on bytecode or on source, I don't mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Clirr](http://clirr.sourceforge.net/) is a tool that checks Java libraries for binary and source compatibility with older releases.

Apache Commons use it, it creates [reports like this (for Commons Lang)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/clirr-report.html).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [japitools](http://sab39.netreach.com/japi/).  These tools are used by the GNU Classpath project to compare their APIs for signature compatibility with different versions of the Sun Java class libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own tool using [reflection](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/), especially if you want to examine distinct changes of your code. It also works with bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the [JDiff doclet](http://www.jdiff.org/) in the past for this.  Depending what you're doing it can be a pain to setup but I think the Ant task works fairly well.